# How do I use findViewById() in onCreate without it returning null?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, oncreate, findviewbyid

I don't know how to use `findViewById(R.id.nav_timetable);` without it returning null and creating an NPE. What I'm trying to do is make the TimetableFragment get loaded by default and then people can use the drawer to go to other fragments.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setupDrawer(toolbar);

    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); // Opened this on first run so they know what's in it.

    // TODO Change this later to a home page and remove goToTimetablePage();
    // goToTimetablePage();
    goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem((MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_timetable));
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem(menuItem);
    return true;
}

private void goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_slideshow: // TODO fragmentClass = SlideshowFragment.class; break;
        case R.id.nav_share: // TODO fragmentClass = ShareFragment.class; break;
        case R.id.nav_timetable:
            fragmentClass = TimetableFragment.class;
            // goToTimetablePage();
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = TimetableFragment.class;
            // TODO Change this later to a home page:
            // TODO fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class; Remove "goToTimetablePage();"
    }


    //noinspection TryWithIdenticalCatches
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead/com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference
  at com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead.MainActivity.goToNavFragment(MainActivity.java:123)
  at com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I tried using the `onCreateView` method but it just made stackoverflow messages for some reason.

EDIT: Here's all the code to clear up any confusion: https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead

EDIT2: Make sure you don't worry about the `goToTimetablePage()` method. It's unused at the moment and I plan on moving it to the `TimetableFragment` fragment.

EDIT3: I changed the method name to `goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem()` so that it better describes it's actions to clear things up. I also want to let you guys know that the `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)` method works perfectly with the `goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem()` method, it's just that it doesn't work when used inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` because of the `findViewById(R.id.nav_timetable)` returning `null` all the time.

Also, this is my first Android app I've ever made and I'm kinda learning as I make it. I didn't even know what fragments were last night so I'm really new to Android, please don't assume any knowledge.

Comment: post your R.layout.activity_main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the crash due to the **NPE** you can test the returned value to be different by null before passing it:

```
MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_timetable);
if (menuItem != null) {
    goToNavFragment(menuItem);
}
```

Anyway, that will not solve your problem, in fact `findViewById(int)` is returning `null` because the view ID you're searching for doesn't exist in your Activity layout.

The method `findViewById()`, which comes from the `View` class and you're invoking it on `this` which is an `Activity` (a Class that extends View), searches for a view id (from `R`) inside the currently inflated layout.

Now, if you take a look to your `onCreate` implementation you see that you're calling the `setContentViewMethod(R.layout.activity_main)`; this means that you're setting the layout of **this** activity taking it from the xml layout with id `activity_main`.

The big problem here is that the layout you're passing (`activity_main`) does not contain the id you're looking for. Just take a look at the `activity_main.xml` layout file, as you can see there's no object with id `R.id.nav_timetable`.

An Activity can only have one layout activity file loaded at once. You can still load other layout files for menus or particular view objects (`Spinner`s, `List`s, etc).

The most important thing here is that you're trying to retrieve a `MenuItem`; to achieve this you have to override two methods `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

---

The `onCreateOptionsMenu()` does what its name says. It creates the options menu you're going to use. Here you can hook your actions but the most important thing you MUST do is to inflate a menu layout. Without this you'll not be able to apply a custom menu layout and to use `findViewById`.

Hence, before invoking the findViewById() you should do like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_id, menu);

    // findViewById()

    return true;
}
```

The `onOptionsItemSelected()` will be called when an item from your previously created menu is selected, it will give you as an argument the selected `MenuItem` and here you can implement the menu item click actions. A standard implementation can be the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_one:
            doSomething()
            return true;
        case R.id.action_two:
            doSomethingElse();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working inside the main activity. Check the question edit for full code. I'll quickly test with the onFinishInflate() method right now and get back to you.

Comment: Apparently "onFinishInflate()" isn't a method to be overriden in an Activity.

Comment: Yes, because it's a Fragment method I thought you were working inside a fragment.

Comment: Sorry, I should've given more information in my question. I've edited it now though.

Comment: @gogobebe2 no worries for the misunderstanding, take a look at the edit ;)

Comment: Thanks, what I was trying to do though was to set the timetable fragment as the default fragment that is loaded on app startup. Hence why I put it in onCreate(). I tried what you said and put it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` like this: `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem timetableButton = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_timetable);
        goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem(timetableButton);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }` and it gave the same error of `menu.findItem(R.id.nav_timetable);` being null. Sorry for the late reply, and thanks.

Comment: @gogobebe2 Take a look at the last update, you're receiving a Null Pointer because you're still not inflating the menu layout :)

Comment: Yay! Thanks heaps man! It works!! Now I need to go find out what inflate means :) I'll give you 50 rep for this in 24 hours, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! haha let's say that "to inflate" means (approximately) to insert something inside something else, in this case we're inserting a layout xml inside a java class hence we're inflating it.. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @gogobebe2 i've edited the answer to make it worth the bounty, please tell me if it's still clear or something is missing :)

Comment: The part where you said: "An Activity can only have one layout activity file loaded at once. You can still load other layout files for menus or particular view objects (Spinners, Lists, etc). " was definitely some very important information that helped me understand where I went wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh! 1 more thing. I used `@Override     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {         // Handle navigation view item clicks here.         goToFragmentFromNavMenuItem(menuItem);         return true;     }` instead of the `boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` like you suggested, is that still ok?

Comment: NavigationItem (and `onNavigationItemSelected`) is more appropriate when using a drawer (or navigation) menu. OptionsItem (and `onOptionsItemSelected`) is used with the default android menu

Comment: That's perfect! ;)
Thanks for it! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The way for it not to return null is to pass it a valid Id for the view. Look in your xml design file and use the id in your function like this:

`rootview.findViewById(R.id.your_id_here)`

Comment: I did use a valid id. Take a look at the edit for the full code.

Comment: Please look at edits I've made to my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not include layout files I assume that `R.id.nav_timetable` refers to **fragment**'s ID (and that **it is** part of your layout)? If so, you need to use `findFragmentById()` from `FragmentManager` (or `SupportFragmentManager`) instead of `findViewById()`.

Comment: R.id.nav_timetable refers to the MenuItem in the drawer.

Comment: Please look at edits I've made to my question, thanks :)